# Using React Components to Render TypeScript as Code Blocks in MDX Files

Tags: reactjs, next.js, markdown, documentation-generation

I have a documentation site using [nextra](https://nextra.site/).
In `pages` are the MDX Files and in `samples` are next-app examples.

- pages

  - course
  - docu
- samples

  - app1
  - app2

Now I want to render code from the samples within my docu e.g. as code blocks. I don't want to "hard-code" them as this would mean that I have to change the docu when I change the sample. Instead my idea is to have a React Component, which I can use in my MDX Files, which takes (e.g.) a file as input and renders the contents as code block (markdown syntax).

I'm aware of the existence of [react-markdown](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-markdown) but I'm not sure how to use it correctly.
Any idea how I could possibly achieve this?